# Random 500 errors on IIS

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis

I have been working on an application that provides some web services to a client. The MVC application is built on .Net 4.5 framework. Everything worked fine until we looked at the response statistics our client had generated, where we could see we weren’t responding 100%. The statistics showed response drop to 90%-95% every other day.

**Inspecting the logs**

The first thing I did was to check our application log where I couldn’t find any exceptions logged. We log all (unhandled) exceptions in our application, which would normally lead to an error HTTP status code, so finding no such exception made me think that the request has not reached the application at all. The next step was to check the IIS access logs and there I could not find any 500 errors. I was under the impression that something is going on with the network which is causing 500's.
Upon further investigation, I realized those are being generated by IIS server. I found this by setting up Failed Request Tracing on IIS and after a while I found following error logged:

> ModuleName - ManagedPipelineHandler Notification -
>   EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER HttpStatus - 500 HttpReason - Error Retrieving
>   Data HttpSubStatus - 0 ErrorCode -The operation completed
>   successfully. (0x0)

I've looked at various stackoverflow posts but nothing really helped me. I guess it is because of no of requests we make per minute around 200 requests per minute). But I get response for 90-95% requests.

[Attached detailed error log here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCg8S.png)

Comment: There are ASP.NET 500 errors in the log. Do those show up in the "Event Log" on the server? I assume your own error logging has failed. Can you make the server return the full error details and make the client log? Alternatively, test and fix the server-side logging. Introduce an artificial failure and make sure it is logged.

Comment: “We log all (unhandled) exceptions in our application”, how? Something like ELMAH? https://elmah.github.io/

Comment: yes, logged via Elmah.

Comment: @usr All the failures are logged. I could see other failures in the log. But, I believe these have happened even before they reached the application. Hence we dont see in IIS access logs / application logs.

Comment: Then provide the full exceptions please. The information that's here in the question basically just says "an error occurred" which is not saying much.

Comment: @usr - Is this not helpful? https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCg8S.png

Comment: @Ramji in what way is it helpful in your mind? It just says "an error occurred". We need the exception because it contains type, message and stack of the error.

Comment: Well, I don't see any logs on my server. I don't even see the calls in access logs. I was under the assumption that we can capture missing requests which are not logged by IIS access logs (500's) in Failed Request Logs.
I believe access log would have them if they were coming from IIS. Those logs(500's / missing requests) are generated well outside application code. It would be surprising (not impossible) for IIS to fail but not log the request. Are my assumptions valid?

Comment: It seems the IIS logs have logged the error but not the exception, right? Obtain the exception from the windows event log. ASP.NET unahndled errors get logged there. Also, fix your broken application logging code since it apparently missed this error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the error is. .Net servers don't receive these requests in the first place, these are getting lost in the network. There is an oracle gateway which is buggy and killing few requests.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar case. A website created with angular and asp.net-mvc web api backend.
The website and the back-end respond on different hosts, so we managed the courses in the web api.
The error that is recorded both in the log and in the client is always an HTTP response. Status code 500 is always on the web API.
The endpoints on which it is found are always different.
When the problem arises, if we recycle the application pool the error disappears instantly.

The error, when it occurs, is always on requests of type OPTIONS.

In the active log on requests with outcome 500, the entire pipeline is recorded and the error is reported

```
    101. -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
    
    ModuleName: ManagedPipelineHandler

    Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER

    HttpStatus: 500

    HttpReason: Internal Server Error

    HttpSubStatus: 0

    ErrorCode: Operation complete.  (0x0)

    ConfigExceptionInfo
```

Thanks for the tips